# Timestamp in Excel with very specific requirements

Tags: vba, excel, datestamp

I need some help with an Excel vba code that can do the following.  I'm a beginner VBA programmer at best, I just need something to work for a spreadsheet I'm working on.

I know there are countless questions and answers about timestamp codes and I've read a LOT of them, but I can't find one that's specific to my needs.  I've spent hours looking, so that's why I'm asking instead.  Here's what I need:

1. When a cell in column A is changed and the corresponding cell in column B is blank, date stamp the cell in column B with the current date.
2. Subsequently, if a cell in column A is changed and the corresponding cell in column B is not blank (because it already contains a date stamp from a previous change of column A), the date stamp in the cell in column B should not be changed.  This includes if the cell in column A is replaced with the same value.
3. If cell in column A is cleared, either on it's own or as part of a multi-cell select and clear contents, the date stamp in the cell in column B should not be changed OR removed.
4. Only if the date stamp is cleared manually in the cell in column B, should it then be again date stamped with the current date if the value of the corresponding cell in column A is changed again (basically a reset).
5. First row is labels, so do nothing to the cells in the first row.

I hope I've made this clear enough.  If not, please let me know.  Thanks in advance for any and all replies and I'm sorry if this was available somewhere and I just couldn't find it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: You are likely never going to find a code that fits your needs, I encourage you to learn [more about programming](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) or hire someone who does. Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: That's a simple `Worksheet_Change` event (see cyboashu's link), where you only set `Target.Offset(0,1).Value` to `Now()` when `Target.Column` is 1 and `Target.Row` is > 1 and `IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0,1))`.

Comment: @Sgdva - my apologies, when I was trying to search for my answer, this site came up with a lot of hits where people asked and were given answers similar to mine.  I guess I was mistaken.  Is there another website that you would suggest I try instead?

Comment: @YowE3K - where is the cyboashu's link you're referring to?  Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: The link is in cyboashu's comment ^^^^^.  And I'm surprised that all the other answers to questions similar to yours weren't able to give the hints necessary to solve your issue.

Comment: @Verbatim68 While it's explicitly prohibited to refer other websites I may suggest you to define your current path: 1. Are you willing to learn VBA? Look for websites to self learn or roll in a course (you can't expect to walk if you can't crawl am I right?) my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/) 2. If you aren't willing to, look for freelancers in the web. Previous answers have gave you the right scope, which is hard to understand if you don't know how programming works.

Comment: Missed that first comment. I'll bow out of this site and moderators can close or delete this because I'm clearly offending people. I'll just briefly explain that I have not that much need for vba programming and most of what I've done is very simple. like this and I can usually get my answer. I don't feel the need to learn to program as I don't use it that much, I'm just trying to make my department more efficient. I don't feel that the level of programming I need for simple things like this requires me to hire a programmer to work for me, or hire a freelance programmer

Comment: @Verbatim68 As final comment and OT:Respect others work:if you don't know how to do it nor willing to learn,don't expect others to do it for you,nor underestimate their work.Being able to code has costed studies and time effort for many (not at the first attempt either), [this article](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/charles-proteus-steinmetz-the-wizard-of-schenectady-51912022/) may give you a scope of what I'm trying to state. While it's good that you try to optimize the work in your area, don't expect others to do your job in order for you to get the reward just cause you got the idea.

Comment: Point taken.  However, I, as an engineer, have consistently throughout my career given advice and direction on how to do things to other people without any expectation of compensation or credit for the information I have provided to them.  I did it because they came to me and asked for advice and I gave it.  Had they come to me and asked me to design an entire subsea tieback module for free, I would have said no.  I didn't think I was asking for  20 hours of programming work here, just the answer to a simple problem, which is what I thought the internet was for.  Forgive me.

Comment: FWIW, I've also got a sideline business that has to do with a particular fix for certain vehicles.  People come to me for advice on many vehicle related problems that are unrelated to my business, for which I try to give the best possible solution or advice.  Had I a real need for some work in the future, you can be absolutely certain I would go to AleGR for that business instead of you.  You might know everything there is to know about programming, but you have much to learn on business and dealing with people.  You have a very high opinion of yourself and are very condescending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. And give us some feedback, please!

Since you may be applying a change to many cells simultaneously (eg. pressing Ctrl+Enter), I used a loop to navigate through each cell being changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Row > 1 And cell.Column = 1 Then
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the only thing that would make this better is if when I did a "clear contents" on a cell in Column A that did not have a value that it would not then date stamp in the corresponding cell in column B.  That is, if I have a few interspersed rows that have values in column A and corresponding date stamps in B, if I then do a clear contents of a range of cells in A, it leaves the date stamps as it should, but it also then datestamps the column B cells that were empty because A was empty.  I can get around this by filtering first, but if there's a programming fix, that would be better.

Comment: @Verbatim68 I think you will have to use this condition: `If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And cell.Value <> "" Then`